# Spring boot security with jdbc authentication is not working

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, jdbc

**I am applying a simple spring boot security, before today it was working but currently it is not working.**

*This is my security config class, and currently i am not using password encryption.*

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class GameSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    /*private final String USERS_QUERY = "select email, password from userregistrationmaster where email=?";
    private final String ROLES_QUERY = "select u.email, ur.role from userregistrationmaster u inner join authoritiesmaster ur on (u.email = ur.authemail) where u.email=?";*/

     /*@Override
     protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
      auth.jdbcAuthentication()
       .usersByUsernameQuery(USERS_QUERY)
       .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(ROLES_QUERY)
       .dataSource(dataSource);
     }*/

    // Enable jdbc authentication
    @Autowired
    public void configAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
                .usersByUsernameQuery("select email,password, enable from userregistrationmaster where email=?")
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select u.email, ur.role from userregistrationmaster u inner join authoritiesmaster ur on (u.email = ur.authemail) where u.email=?");
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcUserDetailsManager jdbcUserDetailsManager() throws Exception {
        JdbcUserDetailsManager jdbcUserDetailsManager = new JdbcUserDetailsManager();
        jdbcUserDetailsManager.setDataSource(dataSource);
        return jdbcUserDetailsManager;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Bean
    public static NoOpPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return (NoOpPasswordEncoder) NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**");
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/css/**");
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/js/**");

    }

    String[] resources = new String[]{
            "/css/**","/fonts/**","/img/**","/images/**","/js/**","/scss/**","/vendors/**","/jsmaster/**","/SendContactEmail/**"
    };

    String[] lessionChapters = new String[] {
            "/chapter3","/chapter4","/chapter5","/chapter6","/chapter7","/chapter8"
    };

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/login", "/contact", "/about-us","/lessonplan", "/chapter2", "/mobile-apps", "/website", "/game", "/products", "/registration", "/generateOpt", "/userRegistration", "/userLogin", "/forgotpassword").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers(resources).permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/game").hasAnyRole("USER","ADMIN")
        .antMatchers(lessionChapters).hasAnyRole("USER","ADMIN")
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login")
        .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
        .and().logout().permitAll();

        http.csrf().disable();
    }
```

It is not showing any error, but i have created one user with USER_ROLE and trying to login with that username and password, it is showing error page.

Thank you in advance for helping to solve this my issue.

Comment: What error page? What is the error telling you .

Comment: error page meaning is, it is redirecting on failureURL - '.failureUrl("/login?error=true")', seems like it is not finding username and password from bd, but till yesterday it was working properly

Comment: And what is the error? Also the role should be `ROLE_USER` and not `USER_ROLE`. You are also using a `NoOpPasswordEncoder` make sure your passwords are really plain-text then and not encrypted. Also configure the `jdbcUserDetailsManager` to use this, currently you don't. Also remove your `jdbcUserDetailsManager` definition, you already configure that in your `configAuthentication` Your security rules also don't make sense `/game` is `permitAll` but later you want it to be accesible by a `USER` or `ADMIN` (the latter is ignored as the first one will match).

Comment: yes but when i remove that code, i got error " org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'gameController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'jdbcUserDetailsManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.security.provisioning.JdbcUserDetailsManager' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}  "

Comment: Why do you need the `UserDetailsManager` in your controller? Also you should NOT be programming the the concrete class `JdbcUserDetailsManager` but rather the interface `UserDetailsManager` if you really want to use it!.

Comment: ok sir, i will try as you have suggested me to do and thank you for your help.